# How does GWT work or rather how does GWT load the code into the app.html file?

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, mgwt

I would like to know what the `rootPanel` (which is in the entryClass) exactly is, and how GWT loads the Java code into the appname.html file via rootpanel.
What happens there exactly?
Where is the connection between the rootpanel and the HTML file?

I could not find any side which explains this process in a detail. It would be very helpful if somebody could explain it or send some good links to websites which are explaining this issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you checked the sources for `RootPanel` class?

There is a method `RootPanel get(String id)` that returns element (well, widget) from the page depending on the element id you pass in. If you don't pass anything and for example ask for `get()` or `get(null)` you will receive `<body>` as your requested RootPanel instance.

So, you have your index.html with contents:

```
<body>
<div id="myPanel"></div>
</body>
```

in it.

In `onModuleLoad()` method of your entry class you do

```
FlowPanel myNewDiv = new FlowPanel();
// add some styles, more elements and event handlers to myNewDiv
// ...
RootPanel.get("myPanel").add(myNewDiv);
```

Which adds your new div as a child to `myPanel` div which was originally in the html file.

Did this help?