# How is the HTML code integrated in GWT

Tags: html, gwt

I am developing a project with GWT. I use an html component in this way:

```
HTML html=new HTML("<html> bla bal bla </html>");
```

The problem is that I want to know in which file and where my HTML code will end up. Because when I launch the program on the browser and I view the source code of the page I can't see my code, I can only see an iframe. so where is my code " bla bal bla "

Comment: Java is translated to javascript and this javascript is executed in an iframe.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809164/view-gwt-html-source?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Some steps are required to get there. You need a web server at least.
After you get your web server up and running, read through these links

http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/create.html

[How does GWT work or rather how does GWT load the code into the app.html file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13923716/how-does-gwt-work-or-rather-how-does-gwt-load-the-code-into-the-app-html-file/13924283#13924283)